# How to postpone triggering formatter

Tags: sapui5

One of my tables does not load data and throws some error for one of the OData model as undefined.

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.uxap, sap.ui.table"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.ABC": ""}'
  data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
></script>
```

**Controller.js**

```js
_initializeData: function() {
  var parts = {};
  parts.PartsByKey = "SP";
  parts.PriceColumn = false;
  parts.SubTotalColumn = false;
  this.orderMaterialsModel = new JSONModel(Parts);
  this.getView().setModel(this.orderMaterialsModel, "orderParts"); //Line number 6
  this.orderMaterialsModel.setProperty("/OrdersTotal", 0);
  /* works fine till here. But moment above statement is executed,
  the execution goes to the below formatter. The model which is 
  initialized in the next line is never executed, and then the
  formatter throws error - model undefined */
  this.salesOrderModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("salesOrderModel");
  this._validationChecks(this.salesOrderModel.getData());
  this.getView().getModel("salesOrderModel").refresh(false);
  //...
},

// Formatter function for the table rows
formatQty: function(QOH, qty) {
  var oType = this.salesOrderModel.oData.type;
  // error here as this.salesOrderModel does not exists..
},
```

Comment: For other readers, this might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58798785/5846045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the `/OrdersTotal` value, do it asynchronously:

```js
this.orderMaterialsModel.setProperty("/OrdersTotal", 0, /*context*/null, /*async*/true );
```

#### Explanation

Somewhere in your view definition, you must have bound `/OrdersTotal` with the `formatter: '.formatQty'`. Calling `setProperty` without `true` at the end triggers all dependent listeners first (incl. the formatter), **and then** the rest of the code continues.

**Synchronous execution:**

1. In `_initializeData`:

   ```js
   // ...
   this.orderMaterialsModel.setProperty("/OrdersTotal", 0);
   ```
2. In `formatQty`:

   ```js
   var oType = this.salesOrderModel.oData.type; // Error! this.salesOrderModel is undefined
   // ...
   ```
3. Continue `_initializeData` with:

   ```js
   this.salesOrderModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("salesOrderModel");
   // ...
   ```

Passing `true` as the fourth argument in `setProperty`<sup>[API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel/methods/getProperty)</sup> will make sure that the remaining code lines in `_initializeData` are handled first, and all the dependent listeners will be put as the last task to be processed in the call stack.

**Asynchronous execution:**

1. In `_initializeData`:

   ```js
   this.orderMaterialsModel.setProperty("/OrdersTotal", 0, null, true);
   this.salesOrderModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("salesOrderModel");
   //...
   ```
2. In `formatQty`:

   ```js
   var oType = this.salesOrderModel.oData.type;
   // ...
   ```

---

Another issue is that the listeners (e.g. the formatter) will also get triggered when the model is just set.

You can postpone the trigger by setting the model at the end of the callstack, just like the case with async `setProperty`, by using `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
// ...
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  this.getView().setModel(this.orderMaterialsModel, "orderParts");
  // triggers the formatter
}.bind(this));
// ...
```