# Formatter called multiple times or too soon with `undefined`

Tags: data-binding, sapui5, formatter

I'm using OpenUI5. Using the `formatter.js`, I have formatted some text in my view.

But my formatter is called 3 times:

1. When I bind the model to panel control: `oPanel.setModel(oModel, "data");`
   both `sBirthday` and `sFormat`  are `undefined`.
2. After `onInit()` is finished and the view is rendered:
   `sBirthday` is valorized correctly and `sFormat` is `undefined`
3. Again: both `sBirthday` and `sFormat` ara valorized correctly.

Why does this happen? Is it correct?
The app get an error, because the `ageDescription()` in the formatter, can't manage `undefined` values.

**formatter.js**

```js
sap.ui.define([], function () {
  "use strict";

  return {
    ageDescription : function (sBirthday, sFormat) {
      do.something();
      var sFromMyBd = moment(sBirthday, sFormat).fromNow();
      do.something();
      return sAge;
    }
  }
});
```

**main.view.xml**

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="controller.main"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Panel id="user-panel-id">
    <Input id="name-input-id" enabled="false" value="{data>/user/name}" />
    <Label text="{i18n>age}: " class="sapUiSmallMargin"/>
    <Label text="{
      parts: [
        {path: 'data>/user/birthday'},
        {path: 'data>/user/dateFormat'}
      ],
      formatter: '.formatter.ageDescription' }"/>
  </Panel>
</mvc:View>
```

**Main.controller.js**

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "model/formatter"
], function (Controller, JSONModel, formatter) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("controller.main", {
    formatter: formatter,
    onInit: function () {
      var oModel = new JSONModel();
      var oView = this.getView();
      oModel.loadData("model/data.json");
      var oPanel = oView.byId("user-panel-id");
      oPanel.setModel(oModel,"data");
      do.something();
    },
  });
});
```

***data.json***

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Frank",
    "surname": "Jhonson",
    "birthday": "23/03/1988",
    "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    "enabled": true,
    "address": {
      "street": "Minnesota street",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "zip": "94112",
      "country": "California"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the model to the view only when the data request is completed:

  ```js
  onInit: function() {
    const dataUri = sap.ui.require.toUri("<myNamespace>/model/data.json");
    const model = new JSONModel(dataUri);
    model.attachEventOnce("requestCompleted", function() {
      this.getView().setModel(model);
    }, this);
    // ...
  },
  ```

  This ensures that the formatter is called only once (invoked by `checkUpdate(true)` which happens on binding initialization; see below), and no further changes are detected afterwards.
- Additionally (or alternatively), make the formatter more defensive. Something like:

  ```js
  function(value1, value2) {
    let result = "";
    if (value1 && value2) {
      // format accordingly ...
    }
    return result;
  }
  ```

---

> Why does this happen?

1. View gets instantiated.
2. `onInit` of the Controller gets invoked. Here, the file `model/data.json` is requested (model is empty).
3. Upon adding the view to the UI, UI5 propagates existing parent
   models to the view.
4. Bindings within the view are initialized, triggering `checkUpdate(/*forceUpdate*/true)`<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/4a5d78692a9076e02c55e230f62b42faa3d60c6a/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/Binding.js#L456)</sup> in each one of them.
5. Due to the `forceUpdate` flag activated, `change` event is fired, which forcefully triggers the formatters even if there were no changes at all:
   `[undefined, undefined]` → `[undefined, undefined]`. - **1st** formatter call
6. Fetching `model/data.json` is now completed. Now the model needs to `checkUpdate` again.
7. `[undefined, undefined]` → `[value1, undefined]` → change detected → **2nd** formatter call
8. `[value1, undefined]` → `[value1, value2]` → change detected → **3rd** formatter call

Answer (score 0):

Now, given that you are trying to load a static JSON file into your project, it's better to maximize the usage of the `manifest.json`.

That way, you are sure that the data is already loaded and available in the model prior to any binding.

You achieve this by adding the JSON file as a **data source** under **sap.app**

***manifest.json***

```
"sap.app": {
    "id": "com.sample.app",
    "type": "application",
    "dataSources": {
        "data": {
            "type": "JSON",
            "uri": "model/data.json"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, simply add this `dataSource` called `data` as one of the `models` under **sap.ui5**.

```
"sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "com.sample.app.view.App",
        "type": "XML"
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "com.app.sample.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "dataSource": "data"
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you **DON'T need to call this anymore**:

```
var oModel = new JSONModel();
var oView = this.getView();
oModel.loadData("model/data.json");
var oPanel = oView.byId("user-panel-id");
oPanel.setModel(oModel,"data");
```

..as the `data model` we added in the `manifest.json`, is already visible to `oView` and `oPanel` right from the get go.

This way, it doesn't matter if the formatter gets called multiple times, as it would already have the data available to it right from the beginning.

Comment: Was also thinking about suggesting the same but when testing it, I realized that **UI5 actually doesn't wait for the model data to be loaded.** It happens to work many times because the data load is often small, but as soon as it gets bigger or if there is a latency issue, the formatter will be called multiple times again.

Comment: Hmm yes I see your point. I did work on the assumption that his data load was indeed small as his `data.json` seemed to be loading a single "user". In any case, for bigger data sets I would also probably go for something similar to your solution **Boghyon**. Thanks for pointing that out.