# Cannot get Date format using getDateTimeInstance function

Tags: javascript, browser, sapui5

I have a requirement that I need to adjust the date inside the worklist view, based on the date format set in frontend system (in GUI).

My code for formatter.js file:

```
DatePriority: function (sVar1, sVar2) {
                var oDateFormat;
                var oDateFormatFromGUI = sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().getDatePattern("short");

                    oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
                        pattern: "EEE " + oDateFormatFromGUI,
                        UTC: true
                    });
                    return oDateFormat.format(new Date(sVar1));
                }
```

However, oDateFormatFromGUI sometimes does return value, but sometimes it is *undefined*.

[image]
[image]

Is there a specific reason for this behavior? How can I make sure that oDateFormatFromGUI always has the data? Is it because I define it in formatter file, and not at the controller level?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be due to the context from which this method is called. You would have to analyze further to see which context works and which doesn't by looking at the stacktrace in both scenarios.

Comment: I have used also at onInit() in controller file. This function is called first when app loads. There also, sometimes I do receive data, sometimes it is undefined.

Comment: If the context isn't avaiable in the onInit() method, you can try to push it back to onBeforeRendering()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UI5: Formatter called multiple times or too soon from an XML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798785/ui5-formatter-called-multiple-times-or-too-soon-from-an-xml-view)